# Copying Array list values into Another Array list using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

Now i wrote the code for copy an array list values into another array list. Here it's my code.

```
  Try
      Dim billtypeList As New ArrayList
          If frm.cbOriginal.Checked Then
            billtypeList.Add("o")
          ElseIf frm.cbduplicate.Checked Then
            billtypeList.Add("d")
          ElseIf frm.CBTrplicate.Checked Then
            billtypeList.Add("t")
         Else
            For i = 0 To AIMSpecific.G_Bill_Types.Count - 1
                billtypeList.Add(AIMSpecific.G_Bill_Types.Item(i).value)
            Next
        End If
 Catch ex as exception 
     msgbox.show(ex.message)
 end try
```

I getting an error message like this,

```
MissingMemberException was Caught:

    Public member 'value' on type 'ObjectCollection' not found.
```

Please guide me, thanks in advance. :-)

```
   Public class Aimspecific

      public shared  G_BillType as new arraylist

  end class
```

Aimspecific is my base constant class to store the constant variables for my project.

Comment: We need to see the definition for AIMSpecific.G_Bill_Types, I suspect that the object does not have a value property

Comment: Is it a heterogeneous list, first element a string, next element an integer, then a double, then an object or are they all of the same datatype. MS Docs mention using List(Of T) or List(of Object) for better performance.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion buddy. i fixed that issue on yesterday. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, in the else part you have for loop over AIMSpecific.G_Bill_Types and when you getting value you write **AIMSpecific.G_Bill_Types.Item(i).value** that is wrong, the right syntax should be **AIMSpecific.G_BillType(i)** or anything in your object.According to your definition G_Bill_Types should be G_BillType
below, will be right syntax

```
For i = 0 To AIMSpecific.G_BillType.Count - 1
                billtypeList.Add(AIMSpecific.G_BillType(i))
                Next
```

Comment: Please, Give Definition of AIMSpecific.G_Bill_Types

Comment: Hi now i edit my question and give the definition for AIMSpecific.G_Bill_Types

Comment: according to your definition AIMSpecific.G_Bill_Types should be AIMSpecific.G_BillType. which i have corrected in my answer please, try it